# How can I make a purchase by means of calabash-android through Google Play?

Tags: android, automation, automated-tests, calabash, calabash-android

I have tests on ruby - using calabash-android and i want buy vip in my app - through Google Play frame.
In irb console not displayed this google frame. I do not want click on coordinats.

`calabash-android console apk`

`start_test_server_in_background`

`query("*")` = the frame Google Play is not displayed

`monitor` - it command where i can look id elements in app and there appears Google Play fraym

Maybe sambody know how do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using calabash-android we can't automate other apps. Since it instrumented your app, so calabash commands will work for your app only not other apps.

In such cases you can write a python wrapper in your code,  using python android  UI Automator  or adb commands

You achieve two ways

1. Python uiautomator - https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator
2. Adb commands - https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html

Comment: Yes you right its matter of coordinates until your tests are running same screen size device. If you want to run different size of screen device you can go with 1st option or you want to just touch the coordinates you can using following adb command :

system 'adb shell input tap x y'

Comment: It's a good idea, it works for one device, if I use other devices then the coordinates can be other

Comment: yes you are right. if it useful for you vote so other ppl also make use this